# How to run maven selenium project in docker (Maven + Selenium + java + TestNg + docker)

Tags: java, maven, docker, jar

I need to run the selenium test cases into docker. I referred multiple articles are tried the same. I could run the test case in docker which has only selenium set up. But my project is maven build which I want to run in docker.

Project set up :

1. Selenium webdriver with Java
2. Maven as build tool
3. TestNg framework
4. Running test case thru maven run config, which runs the test cases updated in testng.xml

What I understand from few helpful articles:

- need to create test case jar
- create image and run the image in docker.

But I am unable to get the make this setup working.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have experience using TestNg, but I run Selenium testing through maven in docker with the below configuration:

docker-compose.yml (this will allow you to connect to a separate selenium docker container)

```
  image: selenium/standalone-firefox
  volumes:
    - /dev/shm:/dev/shm
  ports:
    - "4444:4444"
  expose:
    - 4444

maven_container:
  build: . # uses Dockerfile
  links:
    - remote-webdriver

  volumes:
    - <your local volume>:<container volume>
  stdin_open: true
  tty: true
  entrypoint: /bin/sh
```

In your pom.xml in the "maven_container" be sure to include the selenium dependency (see below).

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>${selenium.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Finally, the docker image for the "maven_container". Notice we need to copy our local pom.xml over the generic pom.xml generated if we want to run mvn build, etc. before mounting volumes in docker-compose.

```
FROM zenika/alpine-maven
RUN apk update \
    && apk add ca-certificates wget \
    && update-ca-certificates

RUN apk add vim

RUN mvn archetype:generate -B \
    -DarchetypeGroupId=net.alchim31.maven -DarchetypeArtifactId=<intended artifact ID> -DarchetypeVersion=1.7 \
    -DgroupId=com.myproject -DartifactId=MyProject -Dversion=0.1-SNAPSHOT -Dpackage=com.scalascrape
WORKDIR /usr/src/app/MyProject
RUN rm pom.xml
COPY pom.xml .
```

Notice! you will have to wait on the selenium server to boot before you connect to it. This is an important consideration if you want to run your tests with the `docker-compose up` command.